# Powershell Replace String on regex match

Tags: powershell

Need to replace strings after pattern matching. Using powershell v4.
Log line is -

```
"08:02:37.961" level="DEBUG" "Outbound message: [32056][Sent: HTTP]" threadId="40744"
```

Need to remove level and threadId completely. Expected line is -

```
"08:02:37.961" "Outbound message: [32056][Sent: HTTP]"
```

Have already tried following but did not work -

```
$line.Replace('level="\w+"','')
```

AND

```
$line.Replace('threadId="\d+"','')
```

Help needed with correct replace command. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
$line = "08:02:37.961" level="DEBUG" "Outbound message: [32056][Sent: HTTP]" threadId="40744"
$line -replace '(\s*(level|threadId)="[^"]+")'
```

Result:

> ```
> "08:02:37.961" "Outbound message: [32056][Sent: HTTP]"
> ```

Regex details:

```
(                    # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \s                # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *              # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (                 # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
                     # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         level       # Match the characters “level” literally
      |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         threadId    # Match the characters “threadId” literally
   )
   ="                # Match the characters “="” literally
   [^"]              # Match any character that is NOT a “"”
      +              # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   "                 # Match the character “"” literally
)
```

Answer (score 0):

.replace() doesn't use regex.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8  -replace does.